# Prove $|f|$ is constant implies $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

Let $f$ be an entire function (differentiable everywhere over $\mathbb{C})$. Suppose that $|f|$ is constant. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Hint: $|f|\equiv c$ implies that $u^2+v^2\equiv c^2$. Take partial derivatives and apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

---

Proof: Suppose $|f|=c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Writing $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, this means
\begin{equation}
u(x,y)^2+v(x,y)^2=c^2
\end{equation}
Please correct me if I'm not differentiating correctly, but taking the partial with respect to $x$ I find that
\begin{equation}
2u(x,y) u_x(x,y)+2v(x,y)v_x(x,y)=0
\end{equation}
Simiarly, taking the partial with respect to $y$ shows that
\begin{equation}
2u(x,y) u_y(x,y)+2v(x,y)v_y(x,y)=0
\end{equation}
Is this correct so far?

**Edit:** Thanks to AlexR for his tip. I continue the proof below.

Substituting the C-R equations ($u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$), the first equation gives two possible equations:
\begin{equation}
2\left(u(x,y) v_y(x,y)+v(x,y)v_x(x,y)\right)=0
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
2\left(u(x,y) u_x(x,y)-v(x,y)u_y(x,y)\right)=0
\end{equation}

Similarly, depending on the choice of substitution, the second equation gives two possible equations:
\begin{equation}
2\left(v(x,y)v_y(x,y)-u(x,y)v_x(x,y)\right)=0
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
2\left(u(x,y) u_y(x,y)+v(x,y)u_x(x,y)\right)=0
\end{equation}
(does it matter which equations we choose to use?)

Comment: So far, okay. Now apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations to a few of the derivatives.

Comment: You can also use a canon to kill this fly. By Liouville's theorem any entire function which is bounded must be constant. Since $|f|$ is constant therefore $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your derivations are correct, Now substitute the CR-DEs in ($v_x = - u_y, v_y = u_x$) to get these two:
$$2(uu_x-vu_y) = 0\\
2(uu_y+vu_x) = 0$$
Now if $u\equiv c_1$, the equations are satisfied and $v\equiv c_2$ so $f\equiv c_1+ic_2 =: c$
Now assume $u\not\equiv c_1$ and reach a contradiction. As a first step to that, add and subtract the two equations:
$$u(u_x+u_y) + v(u_x-u_y) = 0\\
u(u_x-u_y) - v(u_x+u_y) = 0$$
Note that you may assume $(u_x,u_y) \ne 0$ because $u$ must be $C^\infty$ and thus $u\not\equiv c_1$ implies that its gradient is nonzero on a *subset with an accumulation point* (namely an open ball somewhere in $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: Hi AlexR, thanks for your reply! My C-R equations for a function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ are actually $u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$. Does it matter that yours are slightly different?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree I had a sign error in the post, I fixed it now (it doesn't change much as you see).

Comment: Thanks! I edited my original post. Unfortunately, our equations still aren't quite matching up.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree You should leave out the arguments $(x,y)$ for now to make it more readable, but _adding equations_ means
$$A=B\qquad C=D\\
\Leftrightarrow \begin{align} A+C = C+D\\
A-C=B-D \end{align}$$
Your second possibilites are exactly the equations in my first block (minus the argument lists).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 8):

A short, but different proof can be given by using the fact that a non-constant holomorphic function is an open map: By assumption $f(\mathbb C)$ is contained in a circle in $\mathbb C$ with radius $c$. Any non-empty subset of such circle is not open in $\mathbb C$, hence $f$ is constant, q.e.d.