# Showing that $|f|$ is constant implies $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function (differentiable everywhere over $\mathbb{C}$). Suppose that $|f|$ is constant. Prove that $f$ is constant.

[Prove $|f|$ is constant implies $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1133234/819094)

Here answer is given,but I have tried in an another way.

Since $|f|$ is constant, there exists $K \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|f(z)|\leq K $.

Therefore,$f$ is bounded.

Also,$f$ is analytic.

So, by Liouville's Theorem,$f$ is constant.

Is my proof correct?If not , please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Also, the claim holds if the domain is any connected region, not just for entire functions, so Liouville feels like a bit "too much". (But of course, if $f$ is given as entire, then you are free to do it)